# Is it Possible to prevent Materialize CSS for Single Component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-data-table-component

I am trying to use external package **react-data-table-component** for my tables. I want to use it's default styling and not of **materialize-css** styling. Both of the styles are merged together and cause disturbance. Is there any way to use only one styling? I am using **functional components** not class components. If their is any solution please provide it according to the functional component. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SASS? You can create a custom css file and include just the components you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face this problem, For me I created component and import material ui libraries in each component seperately ,try to use that instead of importing the material ui in the main component
Hope it helps
you can check this out
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page